# Replace function not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

How can I strip the **$** and **,** characters from the following value, the code i am using is not working

```
var asset_value =   second_col.find("input[type=text]").val().replace('$', '');
```

`second_col.find("input[type=text]").val()` looks like

> $1,080.00

**Update**:

I am not sure why i am getting voted down! the duplicate solution does not solve my question, nor does any answer below, except for this, very strange!

```
second_col.find("input[type=text]").val(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/\$|,/g, '');
});

var asset_value =   second_col.find("input[type=text]").val();
```

Comment: `'$1,080.00'.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')` should work.

Comment: note, you don't need to escape `$` when it's inside `[]`

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_". What exactly you expect to get? What you get instead? Errors in the console? Your code [works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/hx5jjck4/).

Comment: '$1,080.00'.replace(/[$,]/g, '');

Comment: Try `second_col.find("input[type=text]").val(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/\$|,/g, '');
});`.

Comment: this is the only solution that seems to work, put htis as an answer

Comment: I am not sure why i am getting voted down! the duplicate solution does not solve my question, nor does any answer below, except for this, very strange! I would not ask such question unless it is the last resort

Comment: It looks like you're expecting the value of the input to change. Why didn't you ask it? You're presenting a snippet, where you assign a replaced value to a variable, there's not a single word about you want to change the value of the input in your question. Hence the question is unclear and not useful, that's why you've got down votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this:

```
second_col.find("input[type=text]").val().replace(/[\$,]/g,'').
```

Assign this value to variable and use it.

Comment: No need to escape the `$` in a character class (ie `[...]`)